# spark.read.format including the empty XML objects in spark dataframe

Tags: xml, azure, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to read the XML file from azure data lake using Databricks. Here is my cluster information. I am able to read the dataframe but it shows whole bunch of null values because the nested XML objects are empty.

```
12.2 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12)
```

I tried a few solutions from stackoverflow but nothing seems to be working. The dataframe should remove all the XML (parent and child objects) if it is empty.

```
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
    .option("rowTag", "Results") \
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls","true") \
    .option("nullValue","null") \
    .option("emptyValue","null") \
    .option("", "null") \
    .load(f"{files}")
```

The other solution I tried is.

```
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
    .option("rowTag", "Results") \
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls","true") \
    .option("nullValue","") \
    .option("emptyValue","") \
    .load(f"{files}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to read an XML file from Azure Data Lake Storage using the procedure below with the same cluster configuration.

I mounted the ADLS path with the following code:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source="wasbs://<containerName>@<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point="/mnt/<mountpoint>",
    extra_configs={
f"fs.azure.account.key.<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net":"<accessKey>"  
  }
)
```

When I tried to read the XML file with the code below:

```
xml_file_path = "/mnt/<mountPoint>/<filePath>/Results.xml"
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
    .option("rowTag", "Results") \
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true") \
    .option("rowTag", "Record") \
    .load(xml_file_path)
df.show()
```

I got an error. It didn't read the XML file. I installed spark-xml 2.12 in the cluster using the procedure below:

Go to the cluster configuration, go to libraries, select `Install new`, select Maven, click on search packages, select Maven Central, search for spark.xml, select XML 2.12 latest version, and click on install. It will install as shown below:

[image]

After installing the package, I tried to read the XML file with the same code, and it read the file successfully, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Bhavani. Thanks for your solution. I am able to read the XML in databricks currently. The problem I'm having is that it shows whole bunch of null values. Any idea how to remove them? They are nested within tags.

Comment: Could you please provide your sample XML?